# FitSCVM - multiple classes, 28x28 matrix of numbers between 0 and 1

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I need to use a SVM to distinguish 28x28 matrices into 9 classes. There are 60,000 training inputs and 10,000 testing inputs.

My current program is as follows:

```
clear;
load mnist.mat
xtest = xtest ./ 255; <--- Normalizing the data
xtrain = xtrain ./ 255;

SVMModels = cell(9,1);
classes = unique(ytrain);
rng(1); % For reproducibility
blah = fitcsvm(xtrain, ytrain);


for j = 1:numel(classes);
    indx = strcmp(ytrain,classes(j)); % Create binary classes for each classifier
    SVMModels{j} = fitcsvm(xtrain,indx, 'KernelFunction','rbf','BoxConstraint',1);
end
```

I believe the problem is due either to the fact that the inputs are 28x28. How do I fix this?

Additional info:

```
xtest: 28x28x10000
ytest = 1x10000
xtrain = 28x28x60000
ytrain = 1x60000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  [`fitcsvm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html) requires that the input training examples is a `N x P` matrix where `N` is the total number of samples and `P` is the total number of features.  What you have to do in your case is **reshape** your array so that `xtrain` and `xtest` are `60000 x 784`.  The 784 is due to `28 x 28`.  Specifically, you must **unroll** each slice of your 3D matrix so that it fits into a single vector.  Similarly the class labels must be `N x 1`, so you just need to transpose `ytrain` and `ytest`.

To achieve the desired reshaping, you use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) like so:

```
xtrain_final = reshape(xtrain, 784, 60000).'; %'
xtest_final = reshape(xtest, 784, 60000).'; %'
ytrain_final = ytrain.'; %'
ytest_final = ytest.'; %'
```

Now the reshaping of the training and testing examples is a bit odd.  How MATLAB works when reshaping is that it performs this on a **column** major basis.  This means that when you reshape, it takes columns at a time to produce your results.  As such, because your matrix is `28 x 28 x 60000`, each slice of your 3D matrix is `28 x 28`.  Therefore, to facilitate the column major ordering, you take each 2D slice and fit it to a single column.  You would thus have 60000 columns corresponding to 60000 training examples.  The last thing you need to do now is transpose this result to get what is required for `fitcsvm`.

Now that this is done, you can train your model.